# Compilation failed error while installing Perl-5.20.2

Tags: perl

I am trying to install perl-5.20.2 and running into a compilation error. Here are the steps that I executed.

1. tar -xzf perl-5.20.2.tar.gz
2. ./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
3. make
4. make test

The installation got stuck after running fine for some time at the following line:

```
cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/t/writemakefile_args .................. ok

cpan/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/t/xs .................................. ok

cpan/File-Fetch/t/01_File-Fetch ............................... Bareword "Errno::EINVAL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2/cpan/File-Fetch/../../lib/IO/Socket.pm line 135.

Compilation failed in require at /root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2/cpan/File-Fetch/../../lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm line 11.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2/cpan/File-Fetch/../../lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm line 11.

Compilation failed in require at t/01_File-Fetch.t line 178. #Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 100.

FAILED--non-zero wait status: 65280

cpan/File-Fetch/t/null_subclass ............................... ok

cpan/File-Path/t/Path ......................................... do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Timed out
```

I have already tried this process on 5 different Linux(FC25) machines but I see the same response. I would highly appreciate any inputs.

O/p of the command:

```
[root@10 ~]# pwd; perl -ne'print if (1 .. 25) || (130 .. 140)' /root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2/lib/IO/Socket.pm
/root
# IO::Socket.pm
# Copyright (c) 1997-8 Graham Barr <gbarr@pobox.com>.

package IO::Socket;

require 5.006;

use IO::Handle;
use Socket 1.3;
use Carp;
use strict;
our(@ISA, $VERSION, @EXPORT_OK);
use Exporter;
use Errno; 
# legacy
require IO::Socket::INET;
require IO::Socket::UNIX if ($^O ne 'epoc' && $^O ne 'symbian');

@ISA = qw(IO::Handle);
        $err = $sock->getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR);
        $@ = "connect: $err";
        }
        elsif(!@$w[0]) {
        $err = $! || (exists &Errno::ETIMEDOUT ? &Errno::ETIMEDOUT : 1);
        $@ = "connect: timeout";
        }
        elsif (!connect($sock,$addr) &&
                not ($!{EISCONN} || ($^O eq 'MSWin32' &&
                ($! == (($] < 5.019004) ? 10022 : Errno::EINVAL))))
            ) {
```

Comment: have you tried perlbrew?

Comment: I'm looking at the file in the repository as it existed in 5.20.2, and that doesn't make sense to me. After getting the error (well, anytime after `make`), what's the output of `pwd; perl -ne'print if (1 .. 25) || (130 .. 140)' /root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2/lib/IO/Socket.pm`

Comment: @con, `perlbrew` does the same thing, so that won't help. It can theoretically apply patches, but [I don't see anything for 5.22](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-PatchPerl/source/lib/Devel/PatchPerl.pm)

Comment: @con I have not tried perlbrew. I can give it a try if nothing works out

Comment: @ikegami I have updated the post with the o/p of the command you asked as space is limited in the comment section.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable --nay, desirable--  to provide additional info in the question.

Comment: `pwd` shows `/root`, but that's not the dir from where you ran the `make test`, is it? I was trying to confirm that you were in `/root/Desktop/perl-5.20.2` (meaning you didn't pick up the wrong `IO/Socket/INET.pm`).

Comment: Oh woops, I was looking at `IO/Socket/INET.pm`, but the error is from `IO/Socket.pm`. Ok, one mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at `IO/Socket/INET.pm`, we see the following:

```
my $EINVAL = exists(&Errno::EINVAL) ? Errno::EINVAL() : 1;
```

This tells me that `EINVAL` is not available everywhere. The parens in `Errno::EINVAL()` in the constant to be missing until called, which it will never be because of the check.

Now, if we look at `IO/Socket.pm`, we see that `EINVAL` is expected to be present at compile time.

```
elsif (!connect($sock,$addr) &&
    not ($!{EISCONN} || ($^O eq 'MSWin32' &&
    ($! == (($] < 5.019004) ? 10022 : Errno::EINVAL))))
) {
    # Some systems refuse to re-connect() to
    # an already open socket and set errno to EISCONN.
    # Windows sets errno to WSAEINVAL (10022) (pre-5.19.4) or
    # EINVAL (22) (5.19.4 onwards).
    $err = $!;
    $@ = "connect: $!";
}
```

In order to work around this, replace `Errno::EINVAL` with `22` in `dist/IO/lib/IO/Socket.pm`.

Once that's done, re-run `make`. (This should result in `lib/IO/Socket.pm` having the change. If it doesn't pick up the change, try deleting `lib/IO/Socket.pm` and run `make` again.)

Comment: After doing the make again, lib/IO/Socket.pm had changed(EINVAL changed to 22). I saw the same original error after running 'make test'. Here is the snippet of the Socket.pm file that you asked me to grep last time 
elsif (!connect($sock,$addr) &&
                not ($!{EISCONN} || ($^O eq 'MSWin32' &&
                ($! == (($] < 5.019004) ? 10022 : Errno::22))))
            ) {

Comment: I meant replace `Errno::EINVAL` with `22` (so just `22`, not `Errno::22`)

Comment: Hmm. I see. For now, I have copied an already built localperl directory from a good machine to my setup. I will try your suggestion when I enable another setup. Thank you for your responses.